# Second derivative of Capital stock per unit of effective labour

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

Let $K=$capital, $L=$ labour, $A=$ knowledge or effectiveness of labour.  And put $\mathcal{K} = K/AL$ the capital stock per unit of effective labour.  If the following is negative

$$ \displaystyle \frac{\partial \dot{\mathcal{K}}(\mathcal{K})}{\partial \mathcal{K}} \bigg|_{k=k^*} $$

is this then concave down, and if so what does this mean?  More simply I am asking when we have two different partial derivatives of a variable, does it still have the same properties of the usual second derivative?

Comment: On multivariable functions
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292844/how-to-determine-whether-a-function-of-many-variables-is-convex-or-non-convex
The Hessian
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix
On concavity in general
http://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cvn/t

Comment: Okay thank you, then I think we cannot determine concave or convex as we have neither $ \frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{K}}{\partial \mathcal{t}^2} $ nor $\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{K}}{\partial \mathcal{K}^2}$

Comment: The dot above $\mathcal{K}$ is for time variation ? it is hard to say if the stock of capital per capita is concave or convex without other specifications on the functional forms and I don't see the reason why you try to know a form of a time derivative of some variable.

Comment: Yes @optimalcontrol, $\dot{\mathcal{K}}=d\mathcal{K}/dt$.  They look at the first order Taylor-series approximation of $\dot{\mathcal{K}}(\mathcal{K})$ around $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{K}^*$ where $\mathcal{K}^*$ is the value of $\mathcal{K}$ when actual and break-even investment are equal from the book (Advaced Macroeconomics by Romer).  They determined that the above differential was negative, so I was wondering if $\mathcal{K}$ was concave, but I guess it depends on what the other derivatives of $\mathcal{K}$ are.

Comment: I always don't see why it is important to know whether the dynamics of capital accumulation is concave or convex. Normally, in many models, when you simulate the simple solow growth model, you will see a concave shape of capital accumulation like in this paper (page 24) https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00973491/document

It depends especially on initial conditions. It is really difficult to say something with any functional specification as I mentionned above.

Are you trying to look at the Jacobian matrix ? or trying to proove the concavity of some Hamiltonian ?

Comment: Ah thank you too, when I asked the question I was wondering if capital accumulation was always convex, but clearly not; but it makes sense for it to be, so thanks for saying that many models are.  I also do not know why it would be important to know this, I tried to ask this in my question too! (.. for what it would mean).  Nothing about the Jacobian or Hamiltonian .. latter of which is beyond me(: